# Length of multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

If

```
int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

Gives us the length of an array, and `sizeof(arr)` is the size of the array in bytes and `sizeof(int)` gives us the size of the data type of the array,

```
int rowDimension = sizeof(mat)/sizeof(mat[0]);
```

What does `sizeof(matrix)` and `sizeof(matrix[0])` give us?

Answer (score 2):

> What does `sizeof(matrix)` and `sizeof(matrix[0])` give us?

```
int matrix[3][5];  // Assume sizeof(int) --> 4
```

`sizeof(matrix)` is the size of the object/type in bytes.  (60)

`sizeof(matrix[0])` is the size of an element of the object/type in bytes.  (20 since the array element type is `int[5]`).

```
 60/20 --> 3, the number of "rows" in the matrix.
```

---

Better to use `size_t` than `int` for sizing.  `sizeof` returns a `size_t`.

---

The "column" is found

```
 //             5       =        20         /       4 
 size_t columnDimension = sizeof matrix[0] / sizeof matrix[0][0];
```

`()` needed when sizing a type, but not an object.

Comment: Use parentheses around the argument to `sizeof` all the time and you don't have to learn about special cases.  It in no way affects valid code if you always use parentheses.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Such _style_ issues I leave to the group's coding standard. Here I point out possibilities.